# Unable to load data to run deeplearning_mnist_introduction notebook

Tags: python, h2o

I'm trying to run H2O Deepwater using TensorFlow as back end. The [installation](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater) to use it with python ran smoothly without any errors. Now I want to run the [`deeplearning_mnist_introduction` notebook](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/examples/deeplearning/notebooks/deeplearning_mnist_introduction.ipynb) but right at the beginning the function that loads the data returns an error.

```
test_df = h2o.import_file(PATH + "bigdata/laptop/mnist/test.csv.gz")

...
/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/envs/h2o-tf-gpu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.pyc in _process_response(response, save_to)
    723         # Client errors (400 = "Bad Request", 404 = "Not Found", 412 = "Precondition Failed")
    724         if status_code in {400, 404, 412} and isinstance(data, (H2OErrorV3, H2OModelBuilderErrorV3)):
--> 725             raise H2OResponseError(data)
    726 
    727         # Server errors (notably 500 = "Server Error")

H2OResponseError: Server error water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException:
  Error: File /home/my_user_name/h2o-3/bigdata/laptop/mnist/test.csv.gz does not exist
  Request: GET /3/ImportFiles
    params: {u'path': '/home/my_user_name/h2o-3/bigdata/laptop/mnist/test.csv.gz'}
```

My guess would be some hard coded URL that is not longer valid.

Is there a way to fix the URL or just point me to the data set so I can download it manually?

My setup is:

- CentOS 7.3.1611
- Python 2.7.14 (although I can install a different version if necessary)
- h2o-3 (built from nightly, as instructed [here](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater))
- tf 1.4 (pip installed from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl))

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the top of the notebook you will see the below PATH setting which is set to hardcoded path:

```
PATH = os.path.expanduser("~/h2o-3/")
```

First download the dataset from the direct links below and set the proper path:

- [Train Data (train.csv.gz)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/bigdata/laptop/mnist/train.csv.gz)
- [Test Data(test.csv.gz)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/bigdata/laptop/mnist/test.csv.gz)

Now change the PATH to the location where datasets are available:

```
 PATH = "/your_pyhsical_path/"
```

Also make sure test_df and train_df point to correct dataset above.

Note: Deep Water project is no longer in active development so there is no further development from H2O, it is available as it is.